# asp.net mvc publish doesn't overwrite cshtml files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've been publishing my site regularly without too much trouble. But today I noticed that it won't overwrite existing .cshtml razor files with the new versions. I publish, look at the folder, and see the files are still out of date. If I delete the file and then publish, it will put the new version there. But if the file already exists it won't overwrite it and my production website is out of date. I tried doing the option 'delete files before publishing' but it gives me an access error that it can't delete folders. I tried deleting the entire folder but then I lose my .svn folders and it won't recognize version control.

Is there a way to force the Publish command to overwrite my .cshtml files  with the latest version?  (note: the dll files get overwritten fine)

Comment: If you're having .SVN folders on production server then you _definitely_ must be doing something wrong. Maybe you consider moving your published website to another folder?

Comment: How are you publishing?  From Visual Studio using the web deploy settings?

Comment: To publish, I'm inside VS and I right-click on the project and choose 'Publish' using File System.

Comment: What do you have set on cshtml files in Build Action? Should be 'Content'. Also, which MVC/VS versions are we talking about?

Comment: @Thomas. Yes, the Build Action is 'content' and it does publish the file if it doesn't already exist. I'm on VS 2010 MVC 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like Read-Only attribute is set on files, so they can't be overwritten. Check VS Output window for signs of errors.

Advice: Try to NOT include generated files (this also means folder with published files) in source control. VCS tools usually tend to lock-up files they work on.

Having .svn files on Test/Prod server is also not a good idea.

Comment: When I right-click on the .cshtml files, and select Properties, the read-only checkbox is unchecked.

Also, why is it not a good idea to have .svn files on the server? The server is a remote server and copying/pasting files is a HUGE pain. But it's easy to remote into the server and right-click it to get the latest files that have been updated.

Comment: .svn files are just VCS files and they definitely don't belong to project at all, especially at target server. They also pose security risk.

Comment: @user441058: SVN is not designed with publishing in mind and in many cases you may have huge problems with file access. Most probably your question is just of that kind.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I'll look at non-svn options another day. Right now my server has a tendency to crash b/c the Publish option ignores my cshtml files (but not the other files).

Answer (score 5):

Have you set the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always?

I use Build Action = Content too.