# Able to publish files to Azure Slot, but the viewable page isn't updated

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, razor

I've got my main Azure app and I have a staging slot alongside it. I publish to my staging slot, then swap with the main after it's up and running.

I've noticed recently that there is one page where a certain cshtml file (a partial view being embedded in the page) isn't being updated in the view. For example, if I change the file to have a div in it with random text and then publish it, the div will be present in Visual Studio Online, but not in the page itself when it is rendered.

I've cleared my caches, I've deleted and re-downloaded the publish profile, published the entire app and just the single cshtml file, check the file properties to make sure it's set to Content, etc. When I swap with the main app, the old version of the file moves with the slot files and ends up on PROD. I end up with this old version of the file traveling back and forth between staging and prod between deployments.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is the build action for the `cshtml` file correct?  Should be `Content`

Comment: Yep. It's set to Content.

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506550/asp-net-mvc-publish-doesnt-overwrite-cshtml-files?rq=1

Comment: I've tried those things. When I go to the online editor at https://slot-name.scm.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/Views/Shared/_MyPartial.cshtml the changes are present, but when I go to the view that includes that partial, the changes do no show up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like this solution, but I was able to get it working again by deleting the slot and recreating it, then publishing to the new, replacement slot.